# why can not we AUTO-HIDE ADDRESS BAR when document is ready?

Tags: html, mobile-website

In ["MOBIFYING" YOUR HTML5 SITE](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/mobifying/), there is a tip of hiding mobile browser's address bar when window is loaded.
But I am not sure why can't we do this when document is ready. Why document ready won't work?

Answer (score 0):

The code posted in the post

```
{% if is_mobile % }
  // Hides mobile browser's address bar when page is done loading.
  window.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
    setTimeout(function() { window.scrollTo(0, 1); }, 1);
  }, false);
{% endif % }
```

will work even without jQuery, as `$(document).ready()` is a jQuery method.

```
{% if is_mobile % }
  // Hides mobile browser's address bar when page is done loading.
  $(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(function() { window.scrollTo(0, 1); }, 1);
  });
{% endif % }
```

will work just fine.

What you are trying to accomplish isn't very complex. You want to scroll one pixel down at some point very shortly after your client accesses your page.

Comment: $(document).ready() does not work, $(window).load() works. That is why I am confused.

Answer (score 0):

This is also a way of doing it:
[Hiding URL AddressBar on Android in Landscape Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814982/hiding-url-addressbar-on-android-in-landscape-mode/9816449#9816449)

(Question in this case is about android but it works cross-browser.)